# h264 to MP4 file container in C++

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, h.264, mp4, avi

How can I dump a raw h264 from a network camera into a MP4 or AVI file? I am retrieving the H264 packets from a network camera.

Thanks,

Comment: Dear Bali, I have googled for two days without any solution, there is no good examples about muxing on the net. Please, could you help me?

Comment: what's the streaming protocol?

Comment: I am using RTSP (live555), does it matter?

Comment: you should have mentioned live555 in your question, that changes everything. I'll post a sample code ASAP

Comment: Dear Arash, thanks for your help! Currently I am able to save it into the disk by using libav for both rtsp capture and mp4 saving. I will just try to store the whole file into memory since I need to have a circular buffer of frames in order to save a range of video given a timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

Save raw H.264 data to the file and convert it to mp4:

```
ffmpeg -f h264 -i <input file.264> -vcodec <output file.mp4>
```